# Приложение Windows Phone 8 вылетает с сообщением: "The program 'TaskHost.exe' has exited with code -532265403 (0xe0464645)."

Tags: windows-phone-8

Пытаюсь запустить свое приложение на WP8, но оно вылетает со следующим сообщением в Окне вывода: "The program 'TaskHost.exe' has exited with code -532265403 (0xe0464645)." Уже гуглил, но никак не могу найти, что означает этот эксит код.
Ниже прилагаю лог Окна вывода:

```
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\mscorlib.ni.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ni.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Windows.ni.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Net.ni.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.ni.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Xml.ni.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{D579E81A-EDEA-49BF-84AB-3D9815BD72DD}\Install\SRXP.WP8.DLL'. Symbols loaded.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{D579E81A-EDEA-49BF-84AB-3D9815BD72DD}\Install\MvvmCross.WindowsPhone.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{D579E81A-EDEA-49BF-84AB-3D9815BD72DD}\Install\MvvmCross.Core.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Runtime.ni.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{D579E81A-EDEA-49BF-84AB-3D9815BD72DD}\Install\MvvmCross.Platform.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{D579E81A-EDEA-49BF-84AB-3D9815BD72DD}\Install\srxp.core.DLL'. Symbols loaded.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Globalization.ni.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{D579E81A-EDEA-49BF-84AB-3D9815BD72DD}\Install\MvvmCross.Platform.WindowsPhone.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{D579E81A-EDEA-49BF-84AB-3D9815BD72DD}\Install\MvvmCross.Localization.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Resources.ResourceManager.ni.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{D579E81A-EDEA-49BF-84AB-3D9815BD72DD}\Install\microsoft.phone.controls.toolkit.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{D579E81A-EDEA-49BF-84AB-3D9815BD72DD}\Install\microsoft.phone.controls.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{D579E81A-EDEA-49BF-84AB-3D9815BD72DD}\Install\system.windows.interactivity.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\Microsoft.Phone.Interop.ni.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{D579E81A-EDEA-49BF-84AB-3D9815BD72DD}\Install\MvxPlugins.Geocoder.DLL'. Module was built without symbols.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Threading.Tasks.ni.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Collections.ni.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{D579E81A-EDEA-49BF-84AB-3D9815BD72DD}\Install\SQLite.Net.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{D579E81A-EDEA-49BF-84AB-3D9815BD72DD}\Install\SQLite.Net.Platform.WindowsPhone8.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.ObjectModel.ni.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Linq.Expressions.ni.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Core.ni.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Threading.ni.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\Microsoft.Phone.Maps.ni.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{D579E81A-EDEA-49BF-84AB-3D9815BD72DD}\Install\Xamarin.Insights.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Reflection.ni.dll'. Symbols loaded.
mvx:Diagnostic:  0.03 Setup: PlatformServices start
mvx:Diagnostic:  0.03 Setup: MvvmCross settings start
mvx:Diagnostic:  0.03 Setup: Singleton Cache start
mvx:Diagnostic:  0.04 Setup: Bootstrap actions
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Linq.ni.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Runtime.Extensions.ni.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{D579E81A-EDEA-49BF-84AB-3D9815BD72DD}\Install\MvvmCross.Plugins.Email.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{D579E81A-EDEA-49BF-84AB-3D9815BD72DD}\Install\MvvmCross.Plugins.File.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{D579E81A-EDEA-49BF-84AB-3D9815BD72DD}\Install\MvvmCross.Plugins.JsonLocalization.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{D579E81A-EDEA-49BF-84AB-3D9815BD72DD}\Install\MvvmCross.Plugins.Json.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{D579E81A-EDEA-49BF-84AB-3D9815BD72DD}\Install\MvvmCross.Plugins.Messenger.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{D579E81A-EDEA-49BF-84AB-3D9815BD72DD}\Install\MvvmCross.Plugins.PictureChooser.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{D579E81A-EDEA-49BF-84AB-3D9815BD72DD}\Install\MvvmCross.Plugins.ResourceLoader.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{D579E81A-EDEA-49BF-84AB-3D9815BD72DD}\Install\MvvmCross.Plugins.Visibility.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
mvx:Diagnostic:  0.23 Setup: StringToTypeParser start
mvx:Diagnostic:  0.25 Setup: CommandHelper start
mvx:Diagnostic:  0.25 Setup: ViewModelFramework start
mvx:Diagnostic:  0.26 Setup: PluginManagerFramework start
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Reflection.Extensions.ni.dll'. Symbols loaded.
mvx:Diagnostic:  0.28 Ensuring Plugin is loaded for MvvmCross.Plugins.Email.PluginLoader
mvx:Diagnostic:  0.29 Loading plugin assembly: MvvmCross.Plugins.Email.WindowsPhone
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{D579E81A-EDEA-49BF-84AB-3D9815BD72DD}\Install\MvvmCross.Plugins.Email.WindowsPhone.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
mvx:Diagnostic:  0.31 Ensuring Plugin is loaded for MvvmCross.Plugins.File.PluginLoader
mvx:Diagnostic:  0.32 Loading plugin assembly: MvvmCross.Plugins.File.WindowsPhone
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{D579E81A-EDEA-49BF-84AB-3D9815BD72DD}\Install\MvvmCross.Plugins.File.WindowsPhone.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.IO.ni.dll'. Symbols loaded.
mvx:Diagnostic:  0.36 Ensuring Plugin is loaded for MvvmCross.Plugins.JsonLocalization.PluginLoader
mvx:Diagnostic:  0.36 Configuring Plugin Loader for MvvmCross.Plugins.Json.PluginLoader
mvx:Diagnostic:  0.37 Ensuring Plugin is loaded for MvvmCross.Plugins.Json.PluginLoader
mvx:Diagnostic:  0.37 Ensuring Plugin is loaded for MvvmCross.Plugins.Messenger.PluginLoader
mvx:Diagnostic:  0.38 Ensuring Plugin is loaded for MvvmCross.Plugins.PictureChooser.PluginLoader
mvx:Diagnostic:  0.38 Loading plugin assembly: MvvmCross.Plugins.PictureChooser.WindowsPhone
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{D579E81A-EDEA-49BF-84AB-3D9815BD72DD}\Install\MvvmCross.Plugins.PictureChooser.WindowsPhone.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
mvx:Diagnostic:  0.40 Ensuring Plugin is loaded for MvvmCross.Plugins.ResourceLoader.PluginLoader
mvx:Diagnostic:  0.40 Loading plugin assembly: MvvmCross.Plugins.ResourceLoader.WindowsPhone
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{D579E81A-EDEA-49BF-84AB-3D9815BD72DD}\Install\MvvmCross.Plugins.ResourceLoader.WindowsPhone.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
mvx:Diagnostic:  0.41 Ensuring Plugin is loaded for MvvmCross.Plugins.Visibility.PluginLoader
mvx:Diagnostic:  0.43 Loading plugin assembly: MvvmCross.Plugins.Visibility.WindowsPhone
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{D579E81A-EDEA-49BF-84AB-3D9815BD72DD}\Install\MvvmCross.Plugins.Visibility.WindowsPhone.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
mvx:Diagnostic:  0.46 Setup: App start
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{D579E81A-EDEA-49BF-84AB-3D9815BD72DD}\Install\Plugin.Connectivity.Abstractions.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{D579E81A-EDEA-49BF-84AB-3D9815BD72DD}\Install\Acr.UserDialogs.Interface.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\WinMetadata\Windows.winmd'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.ni.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Text.Encoding.ni.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{D579E81A-EDEA-49BF-84AB-3D9815BD72DD}\Install\Sqlite.winmd'. Module was built without symbols.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{D579E81A-EDEA-49BF-84AB-3D9815BD72DD}\Install\Newtonsoft.Json.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.ni.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Dynamic.Runtime.ni.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{D579E81A-EDEA-49BF-84AB-3D9815BD72DD}\Install\Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Net.Primitives.ni.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{D579E81A-EDEA-49BF-84AB-3D9815BD72DD}\Install\Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Net.Requests.ni.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Diagnostics.Debug.ni.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{D579E81A-EDEA-49BF-84AB-3D9815BD72DD}\Install\Plugin.Connectivity.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{D579E81A-EDEA-49BF-84AB-3D9815BD72DD}\Install\Acr.UserDialogs.DLL'. Module was built without symbols.
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in Acr.UserDialogs.DLL
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\en-US\mscorlib.debug.resources.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
The program '[1612] TaskHost.exe' has exited with code -532265403 (0xe0464645).
```

Также заметил и сообщения типа 'Cannot find or open the PDB file.'. эту проблему тоже, к сожалению, пока не удается решить, потому что папка, которая указана в пути, по которому якобы находятся перечисленные библиотеки (а именно: Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs{D579E81A-EDEA-49BF-84AB-3D9815BD72DD}\Install\'), не существует на моем ПК. После двух дней гугления и дебага, идеи закончились.
Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: Это StackOverflow на русском. Здесь пишут по-русски. С английскими вопросами вам на http://stackoverflow.com

Comment: @andreycha Просто Женя Беляев, забыл русский язык, бывает

Comment: Перепутал ветку StackOverflow. Извините, бывает =)

Comment: мне кажется, что дело в этих ошибках  'System.ArgumentException' in Acr.UserDialogs.DLL 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.ni.dll thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException'

Comment: Тогда или переведите, или удалите вопрос.

Comment: user2455111, согласен, этот иксепшн, очевидно, указывает на то, что что-то программа обратилась к компоненту/обьекту, который еще не догрузился, но проблема в том, что во время дебага я не могу проследить, что именно и где не догрузилось. Да и эксит код -532265403 (0xe0464645) мягко говоря не очень информативен.

Comment: andreycha, сейчас переведу.